# Facing issue in Generating entities by IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I'm generating entites from database schemea by using Intellij-idea, but unbale to generate. what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Here is my table columns
[image]

What mistake I'm doing here?

Comment: Have you defined the project/module JDK?

Comment: @LppEdd  It worked!
Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, so other people will understand too.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA features, especially the ones where knowledge of classes is required, require a defined JDK binary installation for the current project/module.

You can set a JDK via the *Project Structure* dialog.

[image]